# In a For Loop, using bs4, how would this function return a df (as a column) and insert it into a final giant df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

For the most part, I've made a scraper using bs4 and a For Loop. I was wondering how to get the final contents of each "For Loop Grab" and put them into a final dataframe.

This is my current code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import bs4 as soup
from numpy.lib.utils import source
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Jacob/Downloads/CEF Tickers.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

#Read in a list of tickers from a spreadsheet

tickers_list = df['Ticker'].tolist()

#final dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickers_list)


for ticker in tickers_list:

#Opening the website
        source = urlopen(Request(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}' , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}))
        
        site = soup.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
        #Getting the exact table
        table = site.find('table', attrs={'id':'ContentPlaceHolder1_cph_main_cph_main_ucPerformance_gvPast20'})

        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
#Building the df with the table
        table8 = []
        for tr in table_rows:
            td = tr.find_all('td')
            row = [tr.text for tr in td]
            table8.append(row)
        df8 = pd.DataFrame(table8, columns=["Period","Price Return", "NAV Return", "Category Price Return", "Category NAV Return"])
        df8 = pd.DataFrame.transpose(df8)
        del df8[0]

        new_header = df8.iloc[0].astype(str)
        df8 = df8[1:]
        df8.columns = new_header

#Making the df into 1 line and then transposing it into a column
        df8 = df8.unstack().to_frame().sort_index(level=1).T
        df8.columns = df8.columns.map('_'.join)
        df8.set_index([f'{ticker}'], inplace = True)
        df8 = pd.DataFrame.transpose(df8)
        data.append(df8)
```

Here is a sample set of tickers:

```
["NIE", "ZTR", "SCD", "GLV"]
```

When I run this I get:

```
KeyError: "None of ['NIE'] are in the columns"
```

But when I run them individually, it works.

I'm still a beginner so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious but for the life of me, I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: df8.set_index([f'{ticker}'], inplace = True), in order to set index as ticker(its value), make sure that the value of ticker is present  in df8 as column. In your case python will look for that particular value of ticker as a column in your df8,  there is no such column as NIE in your df8. so bcoz of this python is not able to set that as Index

Comment: can you try on this line to set the index at 3rd last in your code

df8 = pd.DataFrame(table8, columns=["Period","Price Return", "NAV Return", "Category Price Return", "Category NAV Return"], index = [ticker])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas.read_html` to load a `<table>` into a dataframe. For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0"
}

tickers_list = ["NIE", "ZTR", "SCD", "GLV"]

all_dfs = []
for ticker in tickers_list:
    print("Downloading ticker {}".format(ticker))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(
            f"https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}", headers=headers
        ).content,
        "html.parser",
    )
    df = pd.read_html(
        str(
            soup.select_one(
                "#ContentPlaceHolder1_cph_main_cph_main_ucPerformance_gvPast20"
            )
        )
    )[0]
    df["Ticker"] = ticker
    all_dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs)
print(final_df)
final_df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Prints:

```
   Return Year    Price      NAV Category - Price Category - NAV Ticker
0          YTD   16.49%   20.88%          -10.00%         -3.61%    NIE
1         2019   31.06%   26.09%           29.77%         22.10%    NIE
2         2018   -5.70%   -3.76%           -8.36%         -4.98%    NIE
3         2017   23.69%   16.79%           21.52%         14.50%    NIE
4         2016   11.31%    9.14%           17.59%         13.14%    NIE
5         2015   -5.89%   -1.42%           -9.73%         -7.35%    NIE
6         2014   13.05%    7.31%           11.82%          9.17%    NIE
7         2013   26.06%   25.15%           19.53%         19.58%    NIE
8         2012   13.91%   11.84%           13.72%         13.14%    NIE
9         2011   -8.53%   -2.95%            1.24%          3.22%    NIE
10        2010   17.44%   15.33%           15.07%         13.03%    NIE
11        2009   47.91%   43.66%           43.70%         32.32%    NIE
12        2008  -37.54%  -38.48%          -44.21%        -40.86%    NIE
0          YTD  -23.06%   -7.52%          -15.54%         -9.20%    ZTR
1         2019   59.58%   30.14%           32.69%         22.80%    ZTR
2         2018  -23.48%  -17.43%          -18.78%        -12.01%    ZTR
3         2017   25.10%   22.57%           28.74%         18.14%    ZTR
4         2016   28.99%   15.63%            8.69%          9.54%    ZTR
5         2015   -7.53%   -4.55%           -7.10%         -4.69%    ZTR
6         2014   24.67%   12.66%            7.81%          6.00%    ZTR
7         2013    7.08%   14.39%           21.98%         22.48%    ZTR
8         2012   17.68%   15.29%           18.62%         18.00%    ZTR
9         2011    5.74%    6.29%           -4.51%         -3.46%    ZTR
10        2010   53.75%   48.54%           28.97%         26.03%    ZTR
11        2009   35.12%   26.42%           62.84%         38.80%    ZTR
12        2008  -68.93%  -65.18%          -49.30%        -44.22%    ZTR
13        2007  -44.78%  -41.41%              NaN            NaN    ZTR
14        2006   43.67%   25.40%              NaN            NaN    ZTR
0          YTD  -23.71%  -16.42%          -15.54%         -9.20%    SCD
1         2019   59.11%   38.71%           32.69%         22.80%    SCD
2         2018  -15.39%  -10.43%          -18.78%        -12.01%    SCD
3         2017   14.65%    7.78%           28.74%         18.14%    SCD
4         2016   18.27%   13.03%            8.69%          9.54%    SCD
5         2015  -19.90%  -16.01%           -7.10%         -4.69%    SCD
6         2014   13.37%   12.76%            7.81%          6.00%    SCD
7         2013   26.19%   33.39%           21.98%         22.48%    SCD
8         2012   18.35%   14.32%           18.62%         18.00%    SCD
9         2011    6.45%    4.84%           -4.51%         -3.46%    SCD
10        2010   26.30%   14.83%           28.97%         26.03%    SCD
11        2009   42.20%   29.52%           62.84%         38.80%    SCD
12        2008  -50.71%  -44.43%          -49.30%        -44.22%    SCD
13        2007   11.05%    7.41%              NaN            NaN    SCD
14        2006   19.04%   14.88%              NaN            NaN    SCD
15        2005    5.28%    8.90%              NaN            NaN    SCD
0          YTD   -1.42%   -1.22%          -15.54%         -9.20%    GLV
1         2019   22.25%   13.22%           32.69%         22.80%    GLV
2         2018  -16.15%  -10.39%          -18.78%        -12.01%    GLV
3         2017   22.36%   19.26%           28.74%         18.14%    GLV
4         2016    0.40%   -1.87%            8.69%          9.54%    GLV
5         2015    0.80%   -4.13%           -7.10%         -4.69%    GLV
6         2014    6.55%    4.04%            7.81%          6.00%    GLV
7         2013   21.59%   21.02%           21.98%         22.48%    GLV
8         2012   17.57%   15.31%           18.62%         18.00%    GLV
9         2011  -12.26%  -10.31%           -4.51%         -3.46%    GLV
10        2010   12.33%   12.11%           28.97%         26.03%    GLV
11        2009   55.58%   43.41%           62.84%         38.80%    GLV
12        2008  -45.66%  -40.74%          -49.30%        -44.22%    GLV
13        2007    8.33%   15.57%              NaN            NaN    GLV
14        2006  -10.08%    7.04%              NaN            NaN    GLV
15        2005   35.66%   23.52%              NaN            NaN    GLV
```

And saves `data.csv`:

[image]

Comment: Dang man. I didnt even think of doing that. I originally was trying to use pd.read_html but the website didnt format the tables so they were all in order. This is really smart. Thank you for the good idea.